# express-handlebars isn't finding my layouts or partials

Tags: node.js, express, layout, handlebars.js

I have the following Express 4 view engine setup:

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/layouts"),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"),
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  extname: 'hbs'
});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

I have the following file structure:

```
/views
    error.hbs
    index.hbs
    /partials
        menu.hbs
    /layouts
        layout.hbs
```

And finally in my route: `res.render('index');`

And visiting my site, it loads only my `index.hbs` template. It does not use my `layout.hbs`. I don't get any errors or anything. It just doesn't use the layout even though `layout` is set as my default layout in the handlebars config.

Next I tried to change my code to this:

`res.render('index', {layout: 'layout'});`

Now I get the error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../views/layout.hbs'`

So it's like it's not finding my `layoutsDir`... What am I missing here?

Next I changed it to this:

`res.render('index', {layout: 'layouts/layout'});`

Okay so that worked. My layout is now loaded. But then I added in a partial to my layout:

`{{> menu }}`

Now I get: `/.../views/index.hbs: The partial menu could not be found`

So what is going on here? How come Handlebars isn't recognizing my `layoutsDir` or `partialsDir`? It's just not seeing them at all or something. And how come `defaultLayout` wasn't being used? I had to specify the layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#extnamehandlebars) for express-handlebars if you are changing the file extension from the default `.handlebars` then when you set the view engine, all occurrences of **handlebars** should be replaced with the new extension you wish to use.

So your express setup will need to be updated to:

```
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

Note: the documentation uses a period before the extension e.g. **.hbs** but it seems to work without this.

Full code:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/layouts"),
  partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"),
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  extname: 'hbs'
});

app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server running");
});
```

Comment: I renamed everything to `.handlebars` and removed `hbs` references in my code. No change to my results.

Comment: I updated my post with the full code I used to verify this earlier.  Can you spot any differences? You restarted your app after making the changes right? :)

Comment: Okay for some reason it's working now once I renamed everything to `.hbs` and used your code. Not sure exactly what the difference was previously. Yes I was restarting Node each time. Thank you,

Comment: For anyone curious why this works, it's the difference between app.engine('handlebars',... and app.engine('hbs', ...

Answer (score 0):

In the new handlebars in your use partials you dont have to include its directory in server.js

- The partials are included in  "express-handlebars"
- The first line in view engine setup is responsible for the above

Take note of these.

```
    const hbs = require('hbs');
    const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

//view engine setup
     app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
     app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
     app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
     app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Try to use wildcard on your Dependencies to make sure you match the latest version

```
"dependencies": {  
    "express": "*",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "hbs": "*"
  },
```

Comment: I would not recommend using a pure wildcard in NPM dependencies. Let's say you develop an application that uses version `1.0` of some random dependency. Then 5 years later another person comes along and wants to develop your app. They `npm install` and now everything breaks because that one dependency is now up to version `13.5.3`, and is completely different than version `1.0` was, that your application was written specifically to utilize. Semver standards exists for a reason.